# MySQL transform case-sensitive unique field into unique case-insensitive field

Tags: mysql, uniqueidentifier, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

This is an interesting challenge question as there can be multiple ways to solve this problem :)

I have an ID column that is unique but case-sensitive, ex:

```
----- ID ------
0018000001K6dkh -> record 1
0018000001K6dkH -> record 2 (different from record 1)
```

As MySQL is case insensitive in utf8, it is considering the two ID values as identical:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id='0018000001K6dkh' //returns 2 instead of 1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id='0018000001K6dkH' //returns 2 instead of 1
```

I need to build a MySQL function that I can apply to this column to transform all IDs into a **case-insensitive** and **unique** IDs, ex:

```
function('0018000001K6dkh') = something
function('0018000001K6dkH') = something different
function('0018000000ttzlB') = something even different 
function('0018000000tTzlB') = something even more different
```

**Note:** I don't want to use collations, because I would have to change all the `WHERE`s and `JOIN`s in my application (Laravel PHP). I want to change the IDs permanently.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can change the collation of a field.

Comment: lol you are right, it works. Do you want to answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

> To cause a case-sensitive comparison of nonbinary strings to be case
>   insensitive,  use COLLATE to name a case-insensitive collation.  The
>   strings in the following example normally are case sensitive, but
>   COLLATE changes the comparison to be case insensitive:

```
SET @s1 = 'MySQL' COLLATE latin1_bin;
SET @s2 = 'mysql' COLLATE latin1_bin;
SELECT @s1 = @s2;
```

return false

using @s1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = @s2;

```
SELECT @s1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci = @s2;
```

return true

or use BINARY

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE BINARY  id='0018000001K6dkh'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE  BINARY id='0018000001K6dkH'
```

Comment: I changed the collation of the field from `utf8_unicode_ci` to `utf8_bin` and all the WHEREs and JOINs behave as expected (case-sensitive)

Answer (score 2):

According the official [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) you can set the collation on a per column basis (*see data_type section for CHAR, VARCHAR, *TEXT, ENUM, and SET types*).

This should change the default manner in which they are compared to string literals and each other, but I am not familiar with the rules used when comparing fields of differing collation with each other.

Comment: I changed the collation of the field from `utf8_unicode_ci` to `utf8_bin` and all the WHEREs and JOINs behave as expected (case-sensitive)